# how to select mupltiple values from two drop down and display it in a text area on the click of submit button

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

i want to select multiple values from a drop down ..suppose i have two drop down , one for city and one for country. So i want to select two cities and two countries from drop down and display selected cities and countries in text area on the click of  submit button.
please answer for angular.

Comment: Did you tried anything--

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: did you try this? http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-multi-select-dropdown

Comment: no i did not try anything @Shailendra

Comment: Please make some effort on google to find tutorials about this & little bit effort on try yourself,after that you still suffer than STACKOVERFLOW is here to help you,by the way here is you answer is here
http://jsfiddle.net/6V66F/83/